# CountDownTimer will not run

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Cannot figure out why my CountDownTimer will not run.  I can see that is initializes the timer variables mCountdownInterval and MMillisInFuture correctly when I call start and mStopTImeInFuture seems to increment.

I created a time_up variable to try to set when time is incremented and expired.

I create MyCount class.

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

public byte time_up;

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    time_up=1;
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


    time_up=1;

}
}
```

Then implemtent in MainActivity.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyCount timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timer = new MyCount(10000,250);

    timer.time_up =0;

    timer.start();

    while(timer.time_up==0);

    timer.time_up=0;

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? The timer runs in another thread so access to that variable is not synchronized at all.

Comment: while(timer.time_up==0);  ---  Can't be good.

Comment: I need to make a simple timer to wait for a response from a USB communication link.  IF the response is not received in a certain period of time I need to create a timeout.  I though CountDownTImer could do this, obviously not.  Any other way to create a background timer that can set a variable when my time out occurs?

Comment: I just used Thread.Sleep in a loop for a delay!

Answer (score 0):

Two notes: 1. don't user `byte` for flags, that is what `boolean` is for. 2. `CountDownTimer.onTick()` runs in the UI Thread, which gets blocked with your `while(timer.time_up==0);` loop, so that can not run. Remove the while loop and print some log statements in `onTick()` and `onFinish()` instead.